# Partition into Image in Yocto or Bundle from partition using RAUC

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, swupdate

I am using a Yocto to build custom linux and RAUC(meta-rauc) for updating it.
I have a partition with some custom files and apps and I wanna create a update bundle for it.
I have a pretty simple recipe for partition just copying files from repository and placing them  somewhere into yocto build. And I have a wic plugin which just copies whole folder which contain all files to given partition.

This is quite simple and works well. But now I want to create a update bundle for it and I ran into issue that rauc needs actual artifact to create bundle from. And I am not sure how to do that, it keeps asking for stuff from image class and I tried to implement it somehow but with no luck. I am still kinda new to Yocto so I am a little bit confused how to do this.

Comment: I don't know what you are building for but have you built a wic image for like image-core-minimal you should be able to create a update-bundle from that. Have you seen/ used https://github.com/rauc/meta-rauc-community ?